# Naming a folder

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, screen, launcher

I recently bought a coolpad note 5. In CoolUI when I made a custom folder, there was no option of naming it. Means other already made folder had naming in them but when I tried to made a folder by myself &naming them then there was no option of naming it.

[image: screenshot]

Here you can see that SYSAPP was made since the time I bought this smartphone
Now I made a custom folder of my own (link given in comment sction)

This folder consist of 2 apps setting & coolmanager but you can see that no name is created & also when I click on the  space next to SysAPP. Nothing happens.
See it is like this on home screen

[image: screenshot]

can anyone please tell me how to name a custom folder in coolpad note 5.

```
Specifications are
coolpad note 5
android version-6.0.1
Build number- V029
```

Comment: the folder which I made was http://www.coolpadforums.com/data/attachment/forum/201702/22/061732q5jdpeq3ypczd8d5.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your default launcher doesn't permit the renaming of folders.

The only way to do so is by installing a third party launcher.

I'd suggest you Nova Launcher.